# Do I use ''becomes'' or ''became'' here?

Tags: conditionals

I have a sentence which I'm not quite sure is right:

> The certificate became invalid when the commitments contained in the
> agreement are not fulfilled.

I got confused a little. Shouldn't the word "becomes" replace "became"?

Comment: Becomes. Or became - were not.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This question could be further improved if you explained why you think *became* should actually appear as *becomes.* Have a look at the [Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and scroll down to "How can I ask about checking my text?"